# how to upgrade from php 7.0 to php 7.3 on Debian 9.1

Tags: php, debian, upgrade, digital-ocean

I have a Debian 9.1 droplet on DigitalOcean. 1GB Memory, 30GB Disk.

I've previously installed php 7.0 using
`apt install php php-fpm`

I also ran the following commands to install php modules:
`apt-get install php-mysql`
`apt-get install php-curl`
`apt-get install php-zip`
`apt-get install php-apcu`
`apt-get install php-xml`

How do I now upgrade from 7.0 to 7.3?

Comment: Different versions, but I am sure the same principles apply:  https://devanswers.co/how-to-upgrade-from-php-7-x-to-php-8-on-ubuntu-apache/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you an idea of how you can do it:

Basically, you need to follow two steps:

1. Install the `7.3` version as you did for `7.0` (you can pass the version number to install the exact version number)
2. You need to configure your PHP CLI to use the new version `7.3` instead of `7.0`.

The above steps can be done for every version.

[Here](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-or-upgrade-php-8-1-on-debian/) is documentation of how you can do it in case of migration from `7 to 8`.

NOTE: The documentation will help you to install a version of PHP and configure CLI so you need to make sure to do the updates as per `7.3`.

Comment: Thanks! If I install 7.3 in addition to 7.0, where will the previously installed 7.0 go? Will it remain on the server and take up space?

The instructions you linked to mention something called Sury PPA for 8.1. What is that, and do I need some version of that for 7.3?

Comment: 1, Yes it will remain on the server you can delete that once you see that 7.3 is working correctly. 2. Sury PPA is for 8.1 so no need for 7.3 the doc is just to help you need to pick and follow steps that are general to specific to any version. Lastly, if the answer is helpful you can mark it as helpful and accept it maybe.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo-apt update
sudo apt-get install php-fpm
```

This will go try to update it if see you already have php-fpm...
Your repository should be updated to understand there is new version of php that is available for download

you can also `remove` & `purge` it and try to download it again...

but also consider some services needs to be updated and set to use last version of php that is currently installed...
Like Nginx ,in that you should update for .conf file to read php 7.3 or any installed versions

you can also check how many versions php do you have by going to directory by this command `cd /etc/php` and do `ls`